# Disable autohide behavior for Global Menu in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, panel

So far, I'm actually pleased with Unity in 14.04.
My only issue is the AppMenu.

And no, I'm not talking about the Unity launcher.
I'm talking about the top panel's global menu.

Is there a way to remove the autohide function? 
And I don't want to see any comments related to CCSM- The option doesn't exist in 14.04.

Thoughts?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the "File", "Edit", and etc menus to be shown even when the mouse isn't hovering over the top bar?

Comment: @TheSchwa Yes. That's exactly what I'm wanting.
It's killing me, man. I would just initiate the local menu option, but I'm looking for a more unified feeling in my desktop.

Comment: @JorgeCastro
I wouldn't have asked if it was a duplicate.
The answers given for that were for 12.04 (If I'm correct) And, as I mentioned above, CCSM doesn't have the option in 14.04.

Comment: A Unity developer is working for a solution in Ubuntu 15.04 (http://www.webupd8.org/2014/12/unity-to-probably-get-option-to-always.html) though I have no idea if 14.04 will get backport.

Comment: I just recently saw that. I'm excited! I think I may just upgrade.